# position += heading*distance_moved TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "Vector") to tuple

Tags: python, indexing, pygame

*although all parts of that operation are tuples python seems to think that in this instance one of them is not. This is my first time trying to make a vector class in python. my intentions are to move my simple mouse image to where i click on the screen by adding increments to  it of a speed * vector to its position until it reaches the target distance*

import math

class Vector(object):

```
#defaults are set at 0.0 for x and y
def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

#allows us to return a string for print
def __str__(self):
    return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)

# from_points generates a vector between 2 pairs of (x,y) coordinates
@classmethod
def from_points(cls, P1, P2):
    return cls(P2[0] - P1[0], P2[1] - P1[1])

#calculate magnitude(distance of the line from points a to points b
def get_magnitude(self):
    return math.sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)

#normalizes the vector (divides it by a magnitude and finds the direction)
def normalize(self):
    magnitude = self.get_magnitude()
    self.x/= magnitude
    self.y/= magnitude

#adds two vectors and returns the results(a new line from start of line ab to end of line bc)
def __add__(self, rhs):
    return Vector(self.x +rhs.x, self.y+rhs.y)

#subtracts two vectors
def __sub__(self, rhs):
    return Vector(self.x - rhs.x, self.y-rhs.y)

#negates or returns a vector back in the opposite direction
def __neg__(self):
    return Vector(-self.x, -self.y)

#multiply the vector (scales its size) multiplying by negative reverses the direction
def __mul__(self, scalar):
    return Vector(self.x*scalar, self.y*scalar)

#divides the vector (scales its size down)
def __div__(self, scalar):
    return Vector(self.x/scalar, self.y/scalar)

def points(self):
    return (self.x, self.y)
```

#The simple mouse move game by Ramon Cabral

```
#imports
import pygame, sys, Vector
from pygame.locals import *
from Vector import *

#game init
pygame.init()

#screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32)

#images
mouse_file = 'mouse.png'
MOUSE = pygame.image.load(mouse_file).convert_alpha()


#variables
bgcolor = (255,255,255)
position = (100.0, 100.0)
heading = Vector(0, 0)

#clock and speed
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
speed = 250.0


#main game function
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            destination = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            heading = Vector.from_points(position, destination)
            heading.normalize()

    screen.fill(bgcolor)
    screen.blit(MOUSE, position)

    time_passed = clock.tick(30.)
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed/1000.0

    distance_moved = time_passed_seconds*speed
    position += heading*distance_moved
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Can you give an example that will cause the error?

Comment: Here is where it goes wrong:                                        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            destination = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            heading = Vector.from_points(position, destination)
            heading.normalize()                                 time_passed = clock.tick(30.)
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed/1000.0
    
    distance_moved = time_passed_seconds*speed
    position += heading * distance_moved

Comment: i guess when I am trying to add to it is when it goes wrong

Comment: Can you update your question to show what you've tried, and add an example of the code that excepts out? It's quite hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the [**getitem**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [**setitem**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) method to support indexing in your Vector Class.

Comment: I created these but now i am getting an error in __getitem__, I am not really sure how these work.                                     def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self[index] = 1.0 * value
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self[:])

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing `Vector.from_points` a Vector object, when it wants a tuple of numbers. Have you tried something like this?

```
position_points = (position.x, position.y)
heading = Vector.from_points(position_points, destination)
```

I wouldn't recommend making `Vector` support indexing. That's usually reserved for list-like objects. It's not super clear what `Vector()[0]` and `Vector()[1]` should be. `Vector().x` is `Vector().y` are much clearer for me.

If you find that you frequently (read: "more than once") need to treat a vector as a tuple of points, you could make an instance method to do that:

```
class Vector(object):
    # ...
    def points(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
    # ...
```

Comment: I did pass it a tuple I made position= (100.0, 100.0). This is so confusing to me.

Comment: The statement `position += heading * distance_moved` looks like it returns a `Vector`. `heading` is a `Vector`, no?

Comment: Yes, heading is the vector created from points position and destination. I want to be able to increment heading.normalize() to position until it reaches destination. basically I want to move my mouse image to where i click on the screen.

Comment: What does `heading * distance_moved` return?

Comment: when i print heading * distance_moved without += to position it prints(0.0,0.0) for ever until i kill the program. actually I am getting a different message now. position += (heading* distance_moved)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "Vector") to tuple

Comment: heading is a tuple. heading * distance_moved is a tuple. and position is also a tuple.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the error you're getting now. Is there a `Vector.__mul__` method that you aren't telling us about? I don't understand how `heading * distance_moved` works.